# About roots of the equation $det(A-\lambda B)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be square real symmetric matrics of the same degree $n \geq 3$ without common isotropics vectors (i.e. there is no a nonzero vector $x\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $x^TAx=x^TBx=0$). 
 Are roots of the equation $det(A-\lambda B)=0$ (with respect to $\lambda$) all real?

Answer (score 2):

No, unless $A$ or $B$ are positive definite. Take for instance $$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right), B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).
$$
and extend it with identities if you really want the dimension to be larger than 3.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I wrote $A$ *or* $B$, so I have that case covered (and what I wrote is more general).

Comment: In the case  $n \geq 3$ theorem from sec.9.11 from W. Greub, Linear algebra, (1967), says that $A$ i $B$ are simultaneously  diagonalizable. This seems to contradicts the above answer.

Comment: @Yourij1 I checked quickly, and from what I understand, that section is about simultaneously diagonalizing bilinear forms, which usually is intended to be a different transformation ($A,B \mapsto MAM^T,MBM^T$, with $M$ not necessarily orthogonal). Anyway, the above answer is a 2x2 counterexample that is easy to verify.